# can you store a line break in a variable?

Tags: bash

Whenever im trying to insert output with a line break into a variable for instance like this:

```
Hello
World
```

Once i do an echo command on the variable i get this:
"Hello World"

Why does it happen and how can i
keep the line break?

Comment: What language? Is this `bash`?

Comment: Quotes: They're important. `echo $var` **does not** show you the literal and unmodified contents of `var`. `echo "$var"` will _mostly_ do so, but if you want something that covers the corner cases, you're better off with `printf '%s\n' "$var"` -- or, to display unprintable characters in a readable form, `printf '%q\n' "$var"`.

Comment: so, moral of this story: Don't trust `echo` to faithfully tell you what you're storing in your variables, and _especially_ don't trust it without proper quoting. Assuming that the problem is with the storage and not with the printing is half the problem.

Comment: That said -- failing to show a demonstration of how you're getting content with linebreaks _into_ the variable makes this a poor question.

Answer (score 3):

In bash, the easiest way to express a literal line break is with `$''` syntax:

```
var=$'Hello\nWorld'
echo "$var"
```

Note that the quotes around `$var` are **mandatory** during expansion if you want to preserve linebreaks or other whitespace! If you only run

```
echo $var
```

...then even though a linebreak is stored in your variable, you will see

```
Hello World
```

on a single line, as opposed to

```
Hello
World
```

on two lines.

---

This happens because when you don't use quotes, the shell splits the expanded words on whitespace -- including newlines -- and passes each item created by that split as a separate argument. Thus,

```
echo "$var"
```

will pass a single string with the entire expansion of `$var`, whereas

```
echo $var
```

will run the equivalent of:

```
echo "Hello" "World"
```

...passing each word in the text as a separate argument to `echo` (whereafter the `echo` command re-joins its arguments by spaces, resulting in the behavior described).

Comment: Well explained answer, thank you very much my friend:)

Comment: It would be more correct to explain that word break is performed on `IFS`. Because, e.g.,: `IFS= var=$'Hello\nWorld'; echo $var` would properly output the newline. Yet, there's another problem when not using quotes: pathname expansion.

Answer (score 0):

Line breaks can be embedded in a string in any POSIX compatible shell:

```
$ str="Hello
> World"
$ echo "$str"
Hello
World
```

If you hit enter before closing the quotation marks, the shell knows you have not yet finished the quoted material, and prints the secondary prompt (`>`) and waits for you to finish the command.