# How to break a line between strings stored in a variable?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

My objective is similar to this [can you store a line break in a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27536954/can-you-store-a-line-break-in-a-variable) but I need it to be in GAS/JS/HTML.

`mesej` is a variable that stores a long string which needs to be displayed as **2 lines** of strings in the html email. That string value is in a gsheet cell `A14`. The line break is displayed just fine in gsheet when I used `\n` in GAS to break a line after symbol `:` but it doesn't happen the same in html email.

I have tried with `<br>` and `%A0` but ended up having that tags appeared in the html email and when I use `mesej.split(":").join(":\n")`, I would get a bounced back email from google support indicates that the email is blocked. Please help to correct my code. Thank you.

**My GS function**:

```
function breakline(){
var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.openById("THIS_SHEET_ID").getSheetByName("job");

//some operations in subfn A
var msg1="Career Status";

//some operations in subfn B
var msg2="Desperately Seeking";

var msg=msg1+":\n"+msg2;
sheet.getRange(14,1).setValue(msg);

var mesej=sheet.getRange(14,1).getValue();//"Career Status:Desperately Seeking" 2 lines in 1 cell

var sampling=HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("sample");
  sampling.mesej=mesej;
  
var mymesej = sampling.evaluate().getContent();
  
MailApp.sendEmail("email@gmail.com","Job Application"," ",{htmlBody:mymesej});
}
```

**My HTML code**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
   <?=mesej?> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't know anything about the specifics of what you're doing, but I'm pretty sure the issue is that your HTML `<br>` is being "escaped." And you need it to not be escaped. See if any reading here helps for a method to _not_ escape the HTML in your string: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates

Comment: How about `var msg=msg1+":<br />"+msg2;`

Comment: After lots of trials and errors, thanks a lot to both @Marc because your link has led me to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28459829/passing-variable-to-html-output-and-then-into-a-scriptlet and @Cooper as the `<br />` can remain as it is and it appears as how I wanted and from there I learnt I could even add in other html tags like `<i><b>` altogether!

Answer (score 0):

answer from Cameron Roberts in [Passing variable to HTML output and then into a scriptlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28459829/passing-variable-to-html-output-and-then-into-a-scriptlet) : we ONLY need to add the `!` in the HTML encoded equivalents to get the desired effect of html tags such as `<br>` tag in our html output. This specifically for scenario where a long string value stored in 1 variable.

In GAS editor:-  `var msg=msg1+":\n"+msg2;` changed to `var msg="<i><b>"+msg1+":</b></i><br>"+msg2;` to get string value in `msg1` in font style italic and bold and then a line break before `msg2` content.

In HTML editor: `<?=mesej?>`  changed to `<?!=mesej?>`